# Зищитить всю страницу с помощью Google reCAPTCHA

Tags: javascript, php, recaptcha

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как поставить reCAPTCHA для проверки всей страницы, а не только форм и в случае подозрительных действий на странице отправить пользователя на страницу с вводом reCAPTCHA и если у него получися пройти ее, то вернуть его на проматриваемую страницу?

Comment: Что такое «подозрительные действия»?

Answer (score 0):

После того как вы определили, что происходят "подозрительные действия" пускай сервер запоминает что нужно сделать проверку капчи

Самый простой вариант как мне кажется создать переменную в сессии

```
$_SESSION['captcha_needed'] = $url_to_return;
```

Если эта переменная есть, то делать редирект на страницу с капчей и после успешного её прохождения делать редирект обратно по url, который хранится в сессии. Перед редиректом удалить эту переменную из сессии чтобы не зациклить.

Но на самом деле капча не панацея, её тоже взламывают.